# Formula similar to SUBTOTAL but with no duplicated values in result

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula but with no luck for now.

My formula should work for the following situation: 
I have a table that reflects data about trainings taken in one department. 
As columns we have:

- Region
- Managers Names
- Trainees Names
- Training Details
- Training Status
- Status Comments

I need a formula that would allow me to say how many people I have trained (with no matter of what exactly training) while I filter any of the columns in the table (by Region, by Manager, by Training Status and etc. )

Important moment here is that when I filter I might have repetitive Trainees Names, but I want the final # of trained people to have included only unique values. I can’t get rid of duplicated Trainee Names in the table itself because it’s ok to have them there (for instance one person have one completed training and another that is currently ongoing and with that I have his/her name appearing twice in the “Trainees Names”  column).  All people in the table passes at least one training.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a PivotTable can do (and more) in Excel 2013. Put everything into FILTERS and `Trainees Names` into VALUES, as Distinct Count.